# Закрываю фото в модальном окне, закрываются оба окна

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup

Проблема: на сайте использую модальное окно, в котором открывается еще одно - с фотографией. Но вот не задача - при закрытии фото, закрываются оба окна. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, куда копать. 
На сайте https://woodstairs.su в самом низу http://joxi.ru/Vm6nJjjt4X4Llm

Comment: при нажатии на оверлей - закрываются окна, по крестику всё нормально
посмотри что закрывает нажатие на оверлей и там уже смотри по ситуации

Answer (score 0):

Преврати ссылку закрытия окна фото

```
<a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a>
```

в ссылку такого вида

```
<a class="pp_close">Close</a>
```

и все получится.

Comment: Всё тут отображается как надо. Используйте markdown. Поправил ваш ответ.

Comment: а как быть с кнопкой ESC? При ее нажатии она также оба окна закрывает